# report viewer do not show fill option

Tags: c#

okay since i have been searching on the internet for 2 days and found nothing, i decided to post a question over here, my problem is that i used to code my application on vs 2012 edition and i just randomly change my computer to another one which it contain vs 2010 everything was okay as long as i was targeting .net 4 platform, i came to a part where i need to create a report viewer which connect to my sql db and collect some information to be printed, the problem is here IT DOES NOT fill the reportviewer1 after searching for a while i found that there was a missing line into my form loading process this line -> `this.reportviewer1.fill(this.TiggoDataSet1._report_pill);`
i add it manually like this but it show error [error while adding the filling line manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzQiI.png)

[allowed report viewer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qktgb.png)
i tried to make a report on a new project it worked fine but it does not work on my current project

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand it.
`ReportViewer` class does not have a method `Fill`. That `Fill` method is likely to be `DataSet.Fill` which it will be bind to `ReportViewer`.

You may find these links useful.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer_methods(v=vs.100).aspx)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/04/28/sql-reporting-services-ssrs-bind-dynamic-dataset-to-your-local-report-with-reportviewer.aspx;